# Twitter archive missing tweets?

Tags: twitter, twitter-archive

I received my Twitter archive a few days ago after requesting it but I noticed that there are tweets that are missing from the archive that are on the site. These are tweets I posted long *before* requesting my archive. Is this a glitch?